# difference between unbalanced data and missing data in ANOVA

Tags: r, statistics, anova, experimental-design

In two-way repeated measure ANOVA,   I was told that aov function cannot deal with unbalanced data.  ez::ezAnova and car::Anova can deal with unbalanced data but not missing data. If there is any missing data, one approach is to use linear mix effect model for that purpose. I'm actually confused about what is the difference of unbalanced data and missing data here in experimental design.  My understanding is in unbalanced design, there are different number of observations for different level combinations (for example, in a two way ANOVA). But I'm confused about what missing data means here..... Can anyone help clarifying this concept? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Unbalanced is when the number of repeats varies between treatments/cases. For example treatments A, B, and C all have 4 repeated measures, but treatment D only has 3. Missing data is when an observation or observations were not collected. 
For example say you have 4 treatments (A,B,C,D) and vegetation was measured in 4 subplots at times 1,2,3,4, missing data would be if the vegetation was not measured in treatment A, subplot 2, at time 3.